# Split Array into multiple Arrays containing string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to take an array of any length (in this example length of 10):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Lime", "Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple", "Date"];
```

From this array I want to take elements in increments of 5, convert each increment into a string, then store each string as a nested array within a new array. Each element will need to be seperated by a '%'.

An output like:

```
newArray = [[ 'Banana%Orange%Apple%Mango%Strawberry' ],[ 'Lime%Kiwi%Melon%Pineapple%Date' ]]
```

To convert into a string I'm using:

```
var finalArray = Array()
    var x = ""
        for(i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
            if(i==fruits.length-1){
                x = x + fruits[i].toString()
            }
            else {
                x = x + fruits[i].toString()+'%'
            }       
        } finalArray.push([x])
```

Which outputs:

```
[['Banana%Orange%Apple%Mango%Strawberry%Lime%Kiwi%Melon%Pineapple%Date']]
```

I've attempted many for & forEach loops, if/else statements etc. in an effort to split the original array into increments of 5 before applying the string conversion code but have not been successful.

Any help or ideas on how to achieve would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks all, this has answered my question :)

Comment: Does it have to be a nested array? Could it not be an array of strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and just crop the array until it's empty:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Lime", "Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple", "Date"];

var result = [];

while (fruits.length) {
  result.push([fruits.splice(0, 5).join('%')]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works absolutely perfectly - Thank you Sebastian for swift and clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could slice the array and join it with the wanted separator.

This approach does not mutate the given data.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Lime", "Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple", "Date"],
    separator = '%',
    size = 5,
    index = 0,
    result = [];

while (index < fruits.length) {
    result.push([fruits.slice(index, index += size).join(separator)]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP seems to be asking for nested array.

Comment: Thanks Nina, I see this works without destroying the original array. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Please, use [array splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it with the required separator.

This approach does not mutate the existing data.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Lime", "Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple", "Date"],
separator = '%',
result = []

while (fruits.length) {
  result.push([fruits.splice(0, 5).join(separator)]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice()` to split and join using desired string `.join()`

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Lime", "Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple", "Date"];

function convert(array, increment, separator) {
    let result = [];
    while(array.length >= 1) {
        result.push([array.splice(0, increment).join(separator)]);
    }    
    return result;
}
console.log(convert(fruits, 5, '%'));
console.log(convert(fruits, 3, '%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Strawberry", "Lime", "Kiwi", "Melon", "Pineapple", "Date"];
const result = []

// Loop over all the fruits.
for(let i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
  // Get the current fruit's sub-index.
  let idx = Math.floor(i/5);
  // Make sure the subarray exists.
  result[idx] = result[idx] || [];
  // Push the current fruit to the subarray.
  result[idx].push(fruits[i]);
}

// Now we have an nested array of arrays, you want to replace the sub-arrays with joined strings.
for(let i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  result[i] = [result[i].join('%')];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice effort - but this can done by doing three lines of code. by using `forEach` and `splice` to it.

Comment: True, but shorter code isn't always easy to understand for beginners. By cutting up the problem into small steps, The process is easier to understand, and hopefully teaches the reader some useful functions.

Comment: I agree - help beginners with extra added info.